# addEventListener doesn't work on browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning javascript and tried creating a web page where the user can switch between dark and light theme, but the browser returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

The problem is that it doesn't work if I use an external js file, how can I fix it?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
// Listen for a click on the button
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Then toggle (add/remove) the .dark-theme class to the body
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
});
```

```css
body {
    --1: #f2f2f2;
    --2: #50250a;
    --3: #181818;
    --4: #ff9100;
    --5: #ffb400;
    --6: #ff325a;
}

body.dark-theme {
    --1: #181818;
    --2: #281400;
    --3: #f2f2f2;
    --4: #ffb400;
    --5: #ff9100;
    --6: #ff325a;
}
  
body{
    background-color: var(--1);
    color: var(--3);
}

a{
    color: var(--5);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover{
    color: var(--6);
}
```

```html
<body class="">
  <button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce in fringilla lacus. Vestibulum ut libero laoreet, dictum odio sed, posuere elit. Nulla semper tempor augue, lacinia vestibulum urna venenatis et. Phasellus a erat et lectus laoreet dictum vitae id nisi. Nam et eros mauris. Etiam interdum urna quis mattis finibus. Phasellus in lorem dapibus, elementum diam et, sagittis quam. Cras eu erat sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque congue vehicula sem, id sodales libero euismod vel. Cras bibendum, nulla id facilisis sollicitudin, quam ligula imperdiet lacus, sed dapibus eros mi quis arcu.
  </p>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Mina the code doesn't find an element. It's relevant to know why an element cannot be found by the code.

Comment: Are you loading the JavaScript before or after the HTML? The error you gave means the element does not exist when the JavaScript is executed. On Stack Overflow, CodePen, etc, they automatically load the JavaScript after the HTML.

Comment: @Mina "*it seems the script run before the DOM get initialized*" which would be a reason for the code to not find the element. Which is described in the duplicate. That is why the duplicate is relevant.

Comment: @Mina it's jQuery *or DOM methods*. It covers both. Because the cause is exactly the same in either case, regardless on how you look the elements up.

Comment: @Mina the linked question *very clearly* covers more than just jQuery. The accepted answer covers plain JS *first* and eventually mentions jQuery. Same with other answers. And they all do a very good job of explaining what the core of the problem is. It is ***not*** a "jQuery answer" as you claim. It tackles the core of the problem of looking up elements and offers a myriad of solutions. Your very assessment that the script ran before the HTML *matches the very first sentence of the accepted answer*. And you're trying to tell me that it's irrelevant even thought it already said what you said.

Comment: @Mina "*What if I told you that the first time I see the answer title, it doesn't seem related at all to the question?*" then you didn't read it or understand it. "*I event didn't explore the link*" well, I guessed correctly. Protip: try to make informed decisions. Not ones born out of ignorance. You *deliverately* ignored the content of the question to get me to explain it to you, thus wasting both of our times. Next time be so kind to read before you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hypothesis is, your script is executed before the button is created in the DOM. Do you attach the script at the end of your HTML document?

That should work

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <button class="btn-toggle">Click me</button>
</body>
<script>
// script here
</script>
```

and this shouldn't:

```
<script>
// script here
</script>
<body>
    <button class="btn-toggle">Click me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, but I'm using an external js file, how can I do it?

Comment: The same way, just put `<script src="...` below the actual body of the document.

Comment: Or use the `defer` attribute as explained in the Q&A linked at the top of your question.